# how to change text inside tag in XML with python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have multiple XML files in a folder. all the XML files have a `folder` tag in them. this is a sample XML file

```
<root>
  ...
  <folder>./dir_us/</folder>
  <filename>file1.txt</filename>
  ...
</root>
```

I want to open every XML file and change the contents of the `folder` tag to `./root_folder/`

I am able to open the XML file and I am able to read the contents inside the `<folder>` tag. But I am not able to change the text to `./root_folder/`

This is my code so far

```
import os
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

dir = './XML_FOLDER/'

for file in os.listdir(dir):

    tree = ET.parse(os.path.join(dir, file))
    root_xml = tree.getroot()

    for folder in root_xml.findall('folder'):
        folder.text = './root_folder/'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should write the changed object to file.Try this

```
import os
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

dir = './XML_FOLDER/'

for file in os.listdir(dir):

    tree = ET.parse(os.path.join(dir, file))
    root_xml = tree.getroot()

    for folder in root_xml.findall('folder'):
        folder.text = './root_folder/'
    tree.write(os.path.join(dir, file))
```

Comment: understood. I have to write the updated text into the file. works now. thanks

Comment: yah.you should overwrite the same file by saving the updated object.happy coding